# Problem with word wrap (?) in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, word-wrap

I am making great progress on a current project, but of coarse, now I need to go through and fix all the various bugs popping up in Internet Explorer - one of my biggest issues right now is that the text lines for a div added via a jquery script is not wrapping properly.

I tried using this, but didnt work in IE7:

```
.AuthorBlurb, .AuthorBlurb p { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera < 7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */ 
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */   
 }
```

Here is a link to view an example: http://arcaspicio.squarespace.com/insights/2010/7/23/risk-management-for-border-security.html -- when i view it, the "Contributor" info on the left is not wrapping properly in Internet Explorer 7. I have tried all sorts of stuff with no success!

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en) is showing that the containing `<p>` has `white-space: nowrap;` set, coming from `.journal-entry-tag .posted-by`. Most likely IE has the white-space setting overriding the word break, so the whole thing is being treated as one big long single word, hence it running off the screen the way it is.

Comment: Thanks Marc for the tip - still not working though. Works fine in IE8 but not IE7. I set white-space to pre-wrap !important and it seems to be canceling out the inherited nowrap setting, but still not actually wrapping?

Comment: Actually, I revised to white-space: normal !important, which fixed it - thanks!!!